# Change the title of an element by moving the mouse over it

Tags: javascript, function

I want to write a function called `titlep(a)` that when the mouse is on the numbers, their title is equal to the product of  `A` in that number. (The number `A` is always changing and the titles change as it changes)

I want when the mouse is on the numbers +1, +2, +3, +4, the title of these numbers is equal to their product multiplied by the number A.

Can friends help me where is the problem with Function `titlep(a)`?

```js
var number ;

setInterval(function(){ 
    number = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
  document.getElementById("in02").innerHTML = number
  
 
}, 5000);

 function titlep(a){
    
    price =  number * a
    this.setAttribute('title', price );
    }
```

```html
<div style="cursor: pointer">

<span  class="tp-cu-po" onmouseover="titlep(4)" title="333">4+  </span><br>
<span  class="tp-cu-po" onmouseover="titlep(3)">3+  </span><br>
<span  class="tp-cu-po" onmouseover="titlep(2)">2+  </span><br>
<span  class="tp-cu-po" onmouseover="titlep(1)">1+  </span><br>

   

</div><br>

A = <a id="in02"></a>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "title"?

Comment: The attribute should be `onmouseover`.

Comment: yes . Be something like this:` <span  class="tp-cu-po" mouseover="titlep(4)" title="2012">4+ </span>`

Comment: If you change to onmouseover as @SamR suggests then do you still have a problem?

Comment: But even better is "don't use onmouseover attributes on the HTML side, use a normal, modern addEventListener for mouseover on the JS side". It's not HTML4.01 days anymore, if you need an event listener, bind that in your JS, don't use legacy on... attributes. Also, don' t use `innerHTML=...` if you're setting text: use `textContent=...` And if you're using event handling anyway, no need for running code on an interval, trigger a single timeout instead, when you need to, based on changes you control.

Comment: The code snippet has an error.

Comment: Yes . I have a problem again. I think the  `titlep(a)` function has a problem.@AHaworth

Comment: You have undefined variable named `number` in `titlep()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is seemed that you didn't declare any variables with `var`, `const` or `let` so that could be where you were having issues.

By passing `this` as a parameter you can access the exactly which `span` you are hovering. This solution you can change the text of any of those `span`s or even add more and this will still work.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  const number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  document.getElementById("in02").innerHTML = number
}, 5000);

function titlep(elem) {
  const aVal = document.getElementById('in02').textContent;
  const elemVal = elem.textContent.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

  elem.title = Number(aVal) * Number(elemVal);
}
```

```html
<div style="cursor: pointer">

  <span class="tp-cu-po" onmouseover="titlep(this)">4+  </span><br>
  <span class="tp-cu-po" onmouseover="titlep(this)">3+  </span><br>
  <span class="tp-cu-po" onmouseover="titlep(this)">2+  </span><br>
  <span class="tp-cu-po" onmouseover="titlep(this)">1+  </span><br>



</div><br> A =
<a id="in02"></a>
```